# How to get current GMT time in this very format "Sun, 22 Sep 2019 09:18:13 GMT" in python

Tags: python, date, time

Even tho it's not used anymore in favor of UTC, the endpoint i am trying to query requires an hmac signature with a date header in this format : `"Sun, 22 Sep 2019 09:18:13 GMT"`

This deprecated method `new Date().toGMTString();` makes the js sdk works, i need an equivalent in python.

`time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %Z", time.gmtime())` returns the full name (i.e. CENTRAL EUROPE TIME) while `time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %z", time.gmtime())` returns `"Sun, 22 Sep 2019 09:18:13 +0100"`.

The closest i got is`time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime())` which in theory print the right string, but i keep getting this error anyway: `"{\"message\":\"HMAC signature cannot be verified, a valid date or x-date header is required for HMAC Authentication\"}"`

Comment: You should post another question related to that error. Because it seems like everyone else gets the correct output from running the same code. You may try running the code I have in my answer itself without the rest of your code just to make sure its the `datetime` module that causes the error. Try reinstalling `datetime`.

Comment: apparently @MCO nailed it, it looks like it's related to OS. I will probably accept your answer later as it appears to work opposed to `The closest i got istime.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime())` ehich isn't working at all

Comment: %Z is Locale’s time zone name. The best thing you can do other than hardcoding it is using %z and having a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))
```

This works for me :)
[Source of the formattings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Be sure that you use **%Z and not %z**.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time

now = datetime.now() # current date and time

date_time = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", time.gmtime())
# output: date and time: Sun, 22 Sep 2019 10:01:53 GMT
print("date and time in GMT:",date_time)

# output: Local: Sun, 22 Sep 2019 10:01:53 AM UTC
print("Local: " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z\n"))
```

Comment: i am confused as this is exactly the way i've built it according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html and you can look at it in the body of my question. the output is `Sun, 22 Sep 2019 10:03:30 ora solare Europa occidentale` which is not the format i need

Comment: @pep1 you have to use `%Z` insead of `%z`

Comment: if you look at the body of my question i have indeed tried with `%z`, `%Z`, and the format you suggested in your answer @MatejNovosad and @Hermueller so i don't understand why you suggest this solution. Even tho this is the way to get time in GMT, it does not print the format i need at all!

Comment: it *almost* prints the format OP needs, but they want the abbreviated timezone code, e.g. `GMT` instead of  `Greenwich Mean Time`

Comment: strangely, for me, it prints out the right format (GMT) and not the full name.

Comment: @Hermueller you're right, it does on my linux machine... i also checked python versions - python3.6 and 3.7 print `GMT` on my linux, but python3.7 and 2.7 on my windows print `Mitteleuropäische Zeit` (german for MEZ)